# Is it OK to develop on a mid range android phone?

Tags: android

I want to begin development for mobile and android seems like a good choice (with iphone requiring a mac and WP7 not being that popular).
I have a question regarding the testing platform, I'm pretty low on cash and have been wondering if using a mid range phone would hinder my development? I have the ability to buy either a LG Optimus One, a Motorola Milestone or a Nexus One, all representing different segments of the market and each one costing more than the previous.
two concerns I had were screen resolution and CPU power, how much does these two variables matter to development?

Comment: Even though money was tight, when looking to getting into the App development game; buying a mac was the best decision I ever made.

Comment: Eventually I'll do that, but that's 800$ (min) that I just don't have. I can barely scrape the 300 for nexus one which is why I opened the question.

Comment: Yea true, I got a loan (well overdraft) and did it from that. Within a year I'm now working in the UK on a equivalent to over $30k and getting loads of work on the side. I also write Android apps but work-interest is all about the iPhone! As far as android dev goes, get ready to be annoyed about some phones just not playing ball!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

1. Resolution - there are 3 main groups:

   - ldpi - Low Density - devices with screens 240 x 320,
   - mdpi - Medium Density - 320 x 480,
   - hdpi - High Density - 480 x 800, or 480 x 854.

Of course the bigger screen == the more expensive phone.

2 . CPU power - all currently available CPUs (besides a few low-end phones) will propably serve you well (of course, it depends on what do you really want to do)

I, as a developer, would like to add here a third element - which API level (version of Android) are you targeting? Nowadays, 2.1 - 2.3 rocks, and 3+ if the device is a tablet.

Keep in mind, that if you buy a great phone, you may develop application which will be running quite fast on it, but it will not on other low-end devices. Btw, you can always check if all elements will properly layout on the lower screen using built-in emulator(s). So, in my opinion, there is good to have mid-end phone, just to check sth(s).

PS : Nexus one  - AFAIK this phone is a debug version (means you can do a little more than with a standard retail phone :) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you can buy a Nexus One that will serve perfectly. Obviously it doesn't cover every form factor but its BETTER than a midrange phone.

If you come across issues on a specfic device you can always use a cloud debugging service like:

http://www.perfectomobile.com/  (they used to have 2 hours free when you register)

You can emulate the different screen sizes

CPU power depends completely on what you are coding, but most the time you *should* be ok.

Me Personally I've got:

> a Nexus One running 2.3
>
> a HTC G1 running 1.6 (flip out keyboard formfactor)
>
> I also use perfecto for issues with the SonyErricson X10mini (ldpi)
>
> I emulate Honeycomb 3.0 on the PC (altho hoping to buy a XOOM soon).

Comment: +1 Nexus one. This phone was targeted specifically for development.

Comment: The problem is it is the most expensive one too, I changed the question by quite a lot to not make it very local but I can get the optimus fo 100$ a banged up milestone for 200$ and the nexus one costs 300$.... I'll shell out the money if it's that good but it means it's gonna have to wait a bit.

Comment: HTC made the G1, not Motorola.

Comment: I'll add this question, being made for developers: what advantage does it offer for the average market developer? I'm not benefiting from the open bootloader or the OS being open, the only advantage I see is that updates to the OS come fast. I found out that I have an option to get the Motorola Defy on my plan, which is a mid range phone with good specs (800mhz proc and high dpi screen), does the nexus still hold much of and advantage?

Answer (score 0):

Putting on my MBA hat: From a product development perspective it's probably a good idea to make sure your product runs on the widest product segment of whatever platform you're developing for. If that happens to be a mid-range product, your development efforts are probably aimed at the largest market segment and potential customers might be more likely to own/purchase this device. Even better if there's a common platform across all segments. You should probably perform some sort of market analysis to prove this out.